# unable to extract text from href tag using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to extract trends names from [this page](https://twitter-trends.iamrohit.in/) using following xpath

```
//div[@class ='table-responsive']/table[@class = 'table table-striped table-hover dataTable no-footer']/tbody/tr/th/a/text()
```

it gives 50 results while trying on web browser. But with following code

```
import requests
import lxml.html

html = requests.get('https://twitter-trends.iamrohit.in/')
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)
trends_name = doc.xpath("//div[@class = 'table-responsive']/table[@class = 'table table-striped table-hover dataTable no-footer']/tbody/tr/th/a/text()")
```

I get nothing in `trends_name` variable. I have tried to print `html.content` and it gives raw html content. Furthermore I have tried same xpath on online xapth selector using source code of same page and it gives 50 trends
I am not sure what am I doing wrong with code as I have tried it with other sites with different xpaths and it is working, kindly help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `"dataTable"` and `"no-footer"` class names from predicate for `table` - these class names added when table rendered in Browser, but absent in page source:

```
trends_name = doc.xpath("//div[@class = 'table-responsive']/table[@class = 'table table-striped table-hover']/tbody/tr/th/a/text()")
```